# Number of section is not working according to array count in CollectionView

Tags: swift

I have collectionView and I want to display two section if my both array count is grater than 0. if one array count is 0 and another array count is greater than 0 then 1 section otherwise 0 section. but my problem is my one array count is  greater than 0 still there is no section.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    if collectionView == specialityCollection {
        return 1
    } else if collectionView == recentSearchCollection
    {
       
        
        if (self.recentSearchValue?.count ?? 0 > 0)  && (self.pastConsultationList?.count ?? 0 > 0) {
        return 2
    } else if (self.recentSearchValue?.count  ?? 0 > 0) && (self.pastConsultationList?.count == 0)  {
        return 1
    } else if (self.pastConsultationList?.count ?? 0 > 0) && (self.recentSearchValue?.count == 0)  {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
        }
        
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == specialityCollection {
        return self.SpecialtyList?.count ?? 0
    } else {
        if section == 0 {
            return self.recentSearchValue?.count ?? 0
        } else {
            return self.pastConsultationList?.count ?? 0
        }
        
    }
    
}


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
       guard let sectionHeaderView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView", for: indexPath) as? HeaderView else { return UICollectionReusableView()}
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if self.recentSearchValue?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
              sectionHeaderView.headerTitle.text = self.headerTitle[indexPath.section]
        }        } else {
    
    if self.pastConsultationList?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
        sectionHeaderView.headerTitle.text = self.headerTitle[indexPath.section]        } }
    
       return sectionHeaderView
   }
```

Comment: Add breakpoint and check if  your value counts true for every state.

Comment: recentSearchValue may be nil. Try to make breakpoint there and check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your equal comparison when the property is nil since nil *is not equal* to zero so the below will always be false if `pastConsultationList` is nil

```
 pastConsultationList?.count == 0
```

So change it to

```
pastConsultationList?.count ?? 0 == 0
```

and the same for `recentSearchValue` of course

That being said I find the whole inner `if/else` clause a bit messy and I think it can be expressed in a cleaner way, like this for instance

```
let recentSearch = recentSearchValue?.count ?? 0 > 0 ? 1 : 0
let pastConsultation = pastConsultationList?.count ?? 0 > 0 ? 1: 0

return recentSearch + pastConsultation
```

or by first having the AND condition as it is now and then the exact same condition but with OR instead.

Comment: @ShubhangiSingh Any feedback?